# New LifecycleFragment component and old FragmentTransaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to apply new `LifecycleFragment` in my Android application:

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new CustomBlockUrlProviderFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("manage_custom_url_providers");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

`fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new CustomBlockUrlProviderFragment());` and I am getting error on this line. Saying that 2nd argument should be `Fragment`.

How to make it work?

Comment: Are you using Fragment from support library or natively?

Comment: @an_droid_dev yes, natively. Now I have change every fragment to v4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the first line of your code snippet, I am guessing that you are using `android.app.FragmentManager`, and that historically you have been using native fragments (`android.app.Fragment`). `LifecycleFragment` inherits from the fragments backport (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`), and you cannot mix-and-match native and backport fragments in the same activity.

You can create your own `LifecycleFragment`, though:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

public class LifecycleFragment extends Fragment
  implements LifecycleOwner {
  private LifecycleRegistry registry=new LifecycleRegistry(this);

  @Override
  public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
    return(registry);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    registry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    registry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    registry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    registry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    registry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    registry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, switch to the fragments backport (e.g., `FragmentActivity`/`LifecycleActivity`/`AppCompatActivity`, `getSupportFragmentManager()`).

Comment: true, thank you. I have changed all fragments to v4 and it works now

Answer (score -2):

Use fragment manager from the support library `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(...).commit();`